# handle select event of context menu

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, aurelia

I am using Aurelia with Kendo UI. I tried the context menu. I am having problems in calling a function from the select. It is unable to locate that method. Any idea?

```
$("#menu").kendoContextMenu({                
    orientation: orientation,                
    target: "#listview-context-menu",                
    filter: ".product",                
    animation: {                    
        open: { effects: "fadeIn" },                    
        duration: 500
    },                
    select: function (e) {
        this.doAction(); // this function is not being recognized. 
    }
});
```

Comment: Try to use `e => this.doAction()` instead of classic `function(..)` expressions.  You'll avoid a lot of the "wrong `this`" types of issues

Answer (score 0):

When called inside the `select` event, the `this` keyword will refer to `kendoContextMenu` object.  The kendo widget doesn't have a doAction function and the code you provided does not extend the kendo class to include such function.

If you keep a reference to the original `this` context (assuming that the doAction was defined at this level), you'll need to copy before initializing the `kendoContextMenu`:

```
var originalThis = this;
$("#menu").kendoContextMenu({                
    orientation: orientation,                
    target: "#listview-context-menu",                
    filter: ".product",                
    animation: {                    
        open: { effects: "fadeIn" },                    
        duration: 500
    },                
    select: function (e) {
        originalThis.doAction();
    }
});
```

However, if you want to extend specific instance of kendoContextMenu, you could do it like this:

```
$("#menu").kendoContextMenu({                 
    //...
});
$("#menu").data("kendoContextMenu").doAction = function() {
    alert("Action done");
}
```

Note that if the `doAction` make sence for every kendoContextMenu objects, you can also extend the kendo prototype.